# Django Admin dynamic field value

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-forms, django-admin

Here is what I'm trying to do. I have a donation form and once the user fills out their zip code in the form, an ajax call gets triggered to find available pickup routes/dates for that zip. In admin, there is a field called "Missed". If the pickup of the donation was not successful, the call center will make the Missed field as "YES".

My question is after the field gets set as missed, how can I display the list of available pickup dates for that zip so that the donation can be rescheduled?

I'm assuming I'll have to customize the admin change_form.html for my app? Any suggestions?

#### Update

Here is what I have tried so far with no sucess. I decided to make my own view and separate form to deal with this. See my comment below to see what I have tried. Here is the code...

```
def reschedule_donor(request, id):
c ={}
donor = Donor.objects.get(donor_id=id)
zip = donor.zip

two_days_from_today = date.today() + relativedelta(days = +2)
results = PickupSchedule.objects.filter(zip=zip,date__gt = two_days_from_today)     

form = DonateForm(instance=donor)

form['pickup_date'].choices = results

c['results'] = results
c['donor'] = donor
c['form'] = form
return render_to_response('reschedule_donor.html',c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Why don't you write your own view rather than customize the admin?  You'll get much more control doing that.

Comment: @Tadeck, I have broken it out to my own view but dont know how to send the dynamic choices to the field. I have subclassed my main donation form to a RescheduleForm (showing only the pickup_dates field). In my view I lookup the donors ID who had a missed donation and then calculate the next available pickup dates based up that zip. How do I send all those choices to my form? Code is above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you would have to override `change_form.html`. You could create a custom view and load the data with ajax. Or you could override `change_view()` and pass the data to the overridden template in `extra_context`.